# Outlook REST API - Application Permissions or Background Services

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm currently using Microsoft Graph, but have been running into its limitation on the request size. Seeing as how the Outlook REST API doesn't have that limitation and is supposed to be very similar to the Graph API for mail related functions, I wanted to use the Outlook API for sending messages with larger attachments.

But is there a way to get application level permissions with the Outlook REST API? Or make calls without a user? The authentication approach I'm using with Microsoft Graph is the one outlined at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service and it would be nice to be able to do the same with the Outlook API.

My app is registered at the Microsoft Application Registration Portal, but the permissions there are only for Microsoft Graph. I have seen an article that mentions being able to edit the manifest in order to get permissions working with other APIs (like the Outlook API), but wasn't too sure about that.